# Django query taking too much time

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django and django rest framework to make a query from all users in data that have a permission sent as a url parameter but this query is taking too long.

I'm user pycharm debugger how can I try to check why is it taking to long, this is the function:

```
@list_route(url_path='permission/(?P<permission>.+)')
def read_permission(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer_class()
    qs = get_user_model().objects.filter_by_permission(self.kwargs.get('permission'))
    qs = qs.order_by(Lower('username'))
    return Response(serializer(qs, many=True).data)
```

#### Update

Adding the serializer

```
class UserSerializer(UserLabelMixin):
    user_permissions = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, slug_field='codename')

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'is_superuser', 'is_staff', 'label',
                  'full_name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username',
                  'teams', 'date_joined', 'last_login',
                  'user_permissions', 'groups', 'ui_preferences', 'internal_project',
                  'staff_id', 'oem_id', 'oem_email', 'oem_department', 'comment']
        read_only_fields = fields
```

Comment: How long is long here? And how many users are there?

Comment: You can use `django debug panel` (https://github.com/recamshak/django-debug-panel) to check raw sql query and time for each query

Comment: You will not see much in that method as querysets are lazy and will not get evaluated until they are used in the serializer... Maybe you should try to benchmark the queryset, see if it is the db query that takes time or the serialization... Also check is you get duplicates of not (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct).

Comment: @AndreyShipilov ~15 secs. 55 users

Comment: show your serializer please

Comment: @IvanSemochkin added the serializer, thanks

Comment: @CodingMcCodington if all your fields is just model fields it looks fine. If fields include some model properties which hits db, then you need to check that properties and optimize your queries. Here the nice article about django ORM https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2017/04/05/digging-into-django-querysets/

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
get_user_model().objects.prefetch_related("user_permissions", "groups").filter_by_permission...
```

Comment: Prefetching doesn't improve anything here.

Comment: @AndreyShipilov , `serializer(qs, many=True)` will make down the perfomance. Since `User` has inbuilt manytomant relation with group.Please have a look at http://ses4j.github.io/2015/11/23/optimizing-slow-django-rest-framework-performance/

Comment: that doesn't improve anything. Write the tests and read the code.

Comment: it'll improve performance if serializer have nested serializers for related models.

Comment: @Coding Check the update answer. Also Did you override User model? If not, add the `manytomany` or `forienkey` fields inside `prefetch_related`